# How do sexting laws work in the Netherlands?

Tags: criminal-law, internet, netherlands

I've noticed that in some countries the definition of child pornography varies. For example, in Canada, where if a conversation is private between people of a very small age gap and there is never any sharing of the material, then it is considered less severe than malicious possession and distribution.

How does it work in the Netherlands? Is it still looked at as a severe crime even in situations of consent, no further sharing and a minimal age gap (17/19, 16/18, 17/18)?

Comment: This seems to me to have a reasonably narrow focus.

Comment: And? I wonder if there's any precedents in the media about these borderline situations

Comment: I was responding to the 2 votes to close as needing better focus.Mark

Comment: Oh I see, I added more tags

Comment: I clarified a bit further that it's just about the Netherlands and not, say, all of Europe.

Comment: Age of consent is 16. There is only a higher age-limit of 21 for sex workers. There have been prosecutions of teenagers who acted as pimps. But no one is going to be prosecuted for being in a consensual relationship.

Comment: I cannot think of any country that doesn't consider *malicious possession and distribution* more severe that a private (written/text) conversion.

Comment: @RockApe Isn't Possession of Child Pornography a strict liability offence in some countries? Men's rea or malice don't enter into it.